# Problems with @2x images for IOS5 and Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, retina-display

I've been looking for a couple of hours for answers for this problem on both Google and Stackoverflow, and none of the suggestions worked so far, so maybe one of you can tell me what's the problem.

Here's exactly what I'm doing, step by step:

1. Create a 44x44 red square image (test.png) and a 88X88 green square image (test@2x.png)
2. Drag both images to a folder named "Resources" inside my Xcode project
3. Insert the following code inside the controller's viewWillAppear method

   ```
   UIImage *navigationBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navigationBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   ```

After the application is launched on the simulator (iOS 5.1), the bar has a red background, which means that iOS loaded the low resolution image, not the high resolution one.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing a step? Do I have to change the plist file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator is by default in non-retina mode. Make sure you choose iPhone (Retina) from Hardware/Device menu.

I cannot see anything obviously wrong in your posted code.

Comment: Thanks, I always assumed that since the simulator looked like an iPhone 4 it was already on retina mode.